# Attaching a fix integer to a string

Tags: c

Im trying to find a way, so that when the user inputs 2 colors, the program automatically gives each an integer value of my choice.

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

enum color {
    black = 0,
    brown = 1,
    red = 2,
    orange = 3,
    yellow = 4,
    green = 5,
    blue = 6,
    purple = 7,
    grey = 8,
    white = 9 
} colors;

int main(){
    int sum;
    char first, second;
    printf("enter the first 2 colors");
    scanf("%s %s", &first, &second);
    sum = first + second
    printf("%d", colors);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically Im trying to make a Resistor color code calculator and I want the program to recognize whichever color the user inputs as a number. for example if the input is red and orange I want the computer to recognize that as 2 and 3 so that I can make an equation with it.

Comment: ...507, Could you tell me what you are expecting to see as the output when the colours `white` and `red` are entered?

Comment: I would expect the output to be 11

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you need to end each of your statements with a semicolon `;`, there's one missing after the `sum = ...` line.

Just a side note: When you are declaring enumerated types like that, I mean, starting from `0` and increasing by one, you don't have to make any assignments. You could just write `enum color { black, brown, red, ... } colors;` and it would be the same.

As per your answer at comments, you seem to want to print the `sum` out, instead of the `colors`. To do so, change your `printf` line like this:

```
printf( "%d", sum );
```

Another thing; you cannot store a sequence of characters inside a single character. To store a sequence of characters, you need a memory space that can hold a sequence of characters. One way to do that is to declare an array of characters, like this:

```
char first[15];
```

When you do that, your computer automatically allocates `15 * sizeof( char )` big memory for you, first one of them being `first[0]` and the last one being `first[14]`. The address of the first will be `first + 0` or just `first`, and the address of the last will be `first + 14`.

Other way is to manually allocate a memory, I won't get into that.

So, to obtain two strings, your code should look like the following:

```
char first[15];
char second[15];
scanf( "%s %s", first, second );
// notice that I omitted the ampersands (&)
// since first and second are already the addresses
```

Now the sad part: You cannot do what you desire like that. Variable names, enumerated type labels... They all are just labels, they don't mean anything to the computer.

You can, however, do what you desire in many, many ways. I'll offer you the easiest one:

```
// I didn't say it will look beautiful...

#include <string.h>

...

int firstID;

if ( strcmp( "black", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 0;
else if ( strcmp( "brown", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 1;
else if ( strcmp( "red", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 2;
else if ( strcmp( "orange", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 3;
else if ( strcmp( "yellow", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 4;
else if ( strcmp( "green", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 5;
else if ( strcmp( "blue", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 6;
else if ( strcmp( "purple", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 7;
else if ( strcmp( "grey", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 8;
else if ( strcmp( "white", first ) == 0 )
    firstID = 9;
else
    firstID = -1;
```

One way or another, checking if the string you have matches the string you'd like to have will be necessary. [`strcmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) is a function that makes a lexicographical comparison between two strings; returns a negative value if the first string is *less* than the second, i.e. can be found earlier in a dictionary, positive if the opposite, zero if they are the same.

Now, we have written that only for the first one, and it already looks horrible as it is... It would be a good idea to abstract this thing out of our `main`, and put it inside a function. Let's call our function the `colorID`, and define it as follows:

```
int colorID( char colorname[] ){
    if ( strcmp( "black", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 0;
    else if ( strcmp( "brown", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 1;
    else if ( strcmp( "red", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 2;
    else if ( strcmp( "orange", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 3;
    else if ( strcmp( "yellow", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 4;
    else if ( strcmp( "green", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 5;
    else if ( strcmp( "blue", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 6;
    else if ( strcmp( "purple", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 7;
    else if ( strcmp( "grey", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 8;
    else if ( strcmp( "white", colorname ) == 0 )
        return 9;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Now, calling it as `colorID( first );` and `colorID( second );` should give you the individual values you'd like them to correspond.

I have removed the `enum` you had, included `string.h` with `#include <string.h>` (for `strcmp`), added the function `colorID` above as it is, and then changed the `main` to be like the following:

```
int main( ){
    int sum;
    char first[15], second[15];
    printf( "enter the first 2 colors" );
    scanf( "%14s %14s", &first, &second );
    // 14's between % and s are to limit the amount of characters
    // that will be obtained and written

    sum = colorID( first ) + colorID( second );

    printf( "%d", sum );
    getch( );
    return 0;
}
```

And right now, I think it does what I think you were desiring it to do.

Comment: Maybe I should also note that `strcmp` is case-sensitive: `'A'` is *less* than `'B'`, however `'a'` is *more* than `'B'`. It's all about their integer representative values.